# two api response render in table body with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i render two api response **dataOne & dataTwo** in table body with map? Like dataOne in first two tablecell & data two in 3rd tablecell

```
let URL1 = "http://api_url/users"
let URL2 = "http://api_url/users-card"

const promise1 = axios.post(URL1, inputValue , {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}});
const promise2 = axios.post(URL2, inputValue , {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(values) {
  setDataOne(values[0]);
 setDataTwo(values[1]);
});
```

```
 <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
         <TableBody>

             <TableCell>DataOne</TableCell>
              <TableCell>DataOne</TableCell>
              <TableCell>DataTwo</TableCell>

       </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```

Comment: Is there a relation between the two data?

Comment: yes.  i want to display both data into one table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're [using effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for `dataOne` and `dataTwo`, first, declare table cell render function:

```
const renderCell = (content, index) => <TableCell key={index}>{content}</TableCell>;
```

And then use map in the component render function:

```
<TableBody>
    {dataOne.map(renderCell)}
    {dataTwo.map(renderCell)}
</TableBody>
```

Ideally, you should replace index with the row id. Without the `key` React would complain that it is unable to track component state.
More info about keys and lists: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: not starting at same row. Please check this screen shot https://site.pictures/image/xUVyu

Comment: Could you provide a hardcoded html/pseudo-html? In your question all rows from dataTwo are rendered after dataOne directly.